# WSGI - Why does it cache the output for : os.popen("date").read() in multi threads and picks one randomly?

Tags: python, caching, mod-wsgi, wsgi, python-2.6

I woke up and refreshed my wsgi script via web.
within this wsgi script there is this python code.

```
import os
ooo = os.popen("date").read()
```

the system date was incorrect. so i refreshed the wsgi script.

the system time was now showing something that was BEFORE the system time i saw earlier.

the more i refreshed the web browser.. the more i noticed the output is rather random.

the system time was as if..

either python or wsgi was caching it 10 times in 10 different threads and then displaying one randomly from those 10 cached threads.

based on information.. it turns out python is not doing the caching and that WSGI might be responsible for this caching.

well... my understanding was WSGI was simply permitting python to work via web.. i had no idea it was doing things as well such as threading and caching.

i even see suggestions that WSGI is loaded once and thus it can only execute it once.

does this mean i have to reload the WSGI script for every time i want a non-cached result ?

so basically might as well restart the whole apache for everytime i execute a wsgi script on my web site ?

i suppose this means i would be restarting apache 1 million times daily if my web site received that many hits per day ?

how can i tell WSGI to not cache the output for

```
os.popen("date").read()
```

?

Comment: You already have a question open about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166164/how-to-prevent-python-2-6-6-from-showing-cached-results-for-things-such-as-os-po.

Comment: @dano, that question made the assumption that python was responsible for the caching. i deleted that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'caching' happens because the WSGI server/container only loads the application once. After that, for each request it calls the WSGI function. That means that any global (module level) variables will only be initialized once.

Take this simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import time

startup_time = time.ctime()

def application(environ, start_response):
    current_time = time.ctime()
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return [startup_time, '\n', current_time]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref import simple_server
    srv = simple_server.make_server('localhost', 8080, application)
    srv.serve_forever()
```

if you'll run this, you'll see that the first time stays constant, the second doesn't. The same is true if you run this example using a different WSGI server (like apache/mod_wsgi), only that usually multiple instances of the application are launced and used to serve different requests. That explains why you see different values.

So the solution is simple: everything that should be dynamic must be generated within the call to the wsgi function, don't use globals.

Comment: i am still trying to grasp the logic behind how wsgi works and why.. i will soon try to create a bash script with `"date"` command and then execute the bash script via wsgi script to see what happens. `os.popen("sudo /dir/ooo.sh").read()` . i removed the second portion of the code the script works still fine in terms of second time moving correctly. the portion i removed is the one that creates a new server or something.

Comment: amazing.. even the bash script's output is being cached. things are rather crazy.. bash script had "date" command within it. simply ran: ooo = os.popen("sudo /dir/ooo.sh").read()

Comment: o i see i see... it simply has to be placed UNDER the environ line.. anything above it is considered globals.

Comment: wow. even `os.popen("date").read()` works just fine when placed under the environ. all this time people were talking about globals and so on.. all they had to say was.. " place it under environ "...